# Cs-Script & System.Diagnostics.Debug : Overriding Debug output traces

Tags: c#, debugging

Okay, I think the title can be quite confusing... :)

My application is using CS-Script as a script interface.
In the scripts my application will be running, I want to have some sort of "Debug print" - meaning somewhere in the script the scripter can do "Debug.Print("BLAAAAH!!!");") and that would show up somewhere in my very funky output dialog.

Of course I can create my own debug-ooutput-stuff, but since I'm using C# as a scripting language and people using C# would be used to use System.Diagnostics and use Debug.Print("..."),
it would be great if I could reroute System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("") and System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("...") to trace their output to my cool output-window.

So.

Does anybody know if it's possible to reroute C#'s System.Diagnostic.Debug print/writeline output to something I have control over ?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can create a custom [`TraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should set the compile time DEBUG symbol or run the script with /dbg option

```
cscs /dbg <yourScript>
```

You will also need to create a custom [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx) or simply use a trace viewer like the sysinternals [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)

Answer (score 0):

I use the TraceListener for this also, but here's my code snippets:

Classes:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public class DebugOutputListener : TraceListener
{
    public event EventHandler<DebugMessageArgs> DebugMessage;

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        EventHandler<DebugMessageArgs> h = DebugMessage;
        if (h != null)
        {
            DebugArgs args = new DebugArgs
            {
                Message = message
            };
            h(this, args);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        Write(message + "\r\n");
    }
}

public class DebugMessageArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

To receive debug messages, instantiate an instance of the DebugOutputListener, subscribe to the DebugMessage event handler and register the listener with the Debug.Listeners collection.

e.g.

```
private void InitialiseDebugListener()
{
    DebugListener dl = new DebugListener();
    dl.DebugMessage += new EventHandler<DebugArgs>(Console_OnDebugMessage);
    Debug.Listeners.Add(dl);
}


private void Console_OnDebugMessage(object sender, DebugMessageArgs e)
{
    string debugMessage = e.Message;

    // Do what you want with debugMessage.
    // Be aware this may not come in on the application/form thread.
}
```